# Is this a good algorithm to find each week in a given month?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I need to take a month (defined as a start and end date) and return a set of date ranges for each week in that month.  A week is defined as Sunday through Saturday.  A good way to visualize it is if you double click on your Windows date in the start bar:

[image]

The month of October 2011 has 6 weeks: 10/1-10/1, 10/2-10/8, 10/9-10/15, 10/16-10/22, 10/23-10/29 and 10/30-10/31.

I can describe each week as a struct:

```
   struct Range
   {
      public DateTime Start;
      public DateTime End;

      public Range(DateTime start, DateTime end)
      {
         Start = start;
         End = end;
      }
   }
```

I need to write a function that takes a month and returns an array of ranges within it.  Here's my first attempt, which appears to work and addresses the obvious edge cases:

```
public static IEnumerable<Range> GetRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
   DateTime curStart = start;
   DateTime curPtr = start;
   do
   {
      if (curPtr.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
      {
         yield return new Range(curStart, curPtr);
         curStart = curPtr.AddDays(1);
      }

      curPtr = curPtr.AddDays(1);
   } while (curPtr <= end);

   if(curStart <= end)
      yield return new Range(curStart, end);
}
```

I would like to know if there's a cleaner or more obvious approach to do the same.  I'm not overly concerned about performance, but I'd like to improve code readability and make the algorithm a bit more concise.  Perhaps there's a very creative solution involving a single LINQ expression or something.  Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Side note: if you ever plan to go international - you can't define a week as starting on a sunday!

Comment: Thanks!  I was unaware of that site.

Comment: Good point!  Though the algorithm would be fairly easy to modify to take an arbitrary starting day of the week, or read the information from the current thread culture.

Comment: For optimization purposes, once you find the first Saturday you can increment by 7 .... it will reduce the complexity of the computation quite a lot.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but it makes the algorithm a bit more complex and thus bug prone.  I was thinking about toying with that concept though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on simply incrementing by 7, as suggested by Previti, ready for international use. If your C# is < 4.0, remove the default parameter `= DayOfWeek.Sunday`

```
public static IEnumerable<Range> GetRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, DayOfWeek startOfTheWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday)
{
    if (start > end)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    // We "round" the dates to the beginning of the day each
    start = start.Date;
    end = end.Date;

    // The first week. It could be "shorter" than normal. We return it "manually" here
    // The 6 + startOfWeek - start.DayOfWeek will give us the number of days that you
    // have to add to complete the week. It's mod 7. It's based on the idea that 
    // the starting day of the week is a parameter.
    DateTime curDay = new DateTime(Math.Min(start.AddDays((6 + (int)startOfTheWeek - (int)start.DayOfWeek) % 7).Ticks, end.Ticks), start.Kind);

    yield return new Range(start, curDay);

    curDay = curDay.AddDays(1);

    while (curDay <= end)
    {
        // Each time we add 7 (SIX) days. This is because the difference between
        // as considered by the problem, it's only 6 * 24 hours (because the week
        // doesn't end at 23:59:59 of the last day, but at the beginning of that day)
        DateTime nextDay = new DateTime(Math.Min(curDay.AddDays(6).Ticks, end.Ticks), start.Kind);

        yield return new Range(curDay, nextDay);

        // The start of the next week
        curDay = nextDay.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Some small notes: `Math.Min` isn't defined for `DateTime`, so I cheat a little by taking the `Ticks` of the `DateTime`s and comparing them. Then I rebuild the `DateTime`. I always use the `DateTimeKind` of the `start` date.

When you debug `yield` code, remember to "materialize" the result through the use of `ToList` or `ToArray`, otherwise the code won't be executed :-)